# Text-based adventure game

Tags: python, beginner, game

I'm new to programming, and I would like to know if this is the right way to layout code. If anyone has any tips, please share them.

```
import random
import time

def displayIntro():
    print("You are in a land full of dragons. In front of")
    print("you are two caves. In one cave the dragon is")
    print("friendly and will give you his treasure. In the")
    print("other, the dragon is greedy and hungry and will")
    print("eat you on sight")
    print()

def chooseCave():
    cave = ""
    while cave != "1" and cave != "2":
        print("Which cave will you choose? (1 or 2)")
        cave = input()
   return cave

def checkCave(chosenCave):
    print("You approach the cave...")
    time.sleep(2)
    print("It is dark and spooky...")
    time.sleep(2)
    print("A large dragon jumps out in front of you. He opens his jaws and...")
    print()
    time.sleep(2)

    friendlyCave = random.randint(1,2)

    if chosenCave == str(friendlyCave):
        print("gives you his treasure")
    else:
        print("gobbles you down in one bite")


playAgain = "yes"
while playAgain =="yes" or playAgain == "y":

    displayIntro()

    caveNumber = chooseCave()

    checkCave(caveNumber)

    print("Would you like to play again? (yes or no)")
    playAgain = input()
```

Comment: General rules for code layout in Python are stated in [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Comment: This is one of the most suspenseful code examples I've come across. My main bits of advice would be to use a main function instead of the raw script style execution and to store the chosen cave as an int instead of as a string, and then do int comparison instead of string comparison though.

Comment: The code presented seems to be from Al Sweigart's *Invent Your Own Computer Games with Python*, chapter  *Dragon Realm*.

Comment: For anyone in the CV queue, et al.: the code is identical to code on page 57 of [this PDF](https://inventwithpython.com/inventwithpython_3rd.pdf) which supports the claim by greybeard, though there are a couple changes, including string format and capitalization

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ Meant to say page 47 (or 59 if going by the pdf's auto pages)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to other answers you can use 'in' to compare for more than one value.

So

```
while cave != "1" and cave != "2":
    ...
```

becomes:

```
while cave not in ["1", "2"]:
    ...
```

or even:

```
caves = set("12")
while cave not in caves:
    ...
```

Comment: a `set` is a more natural container to check presence

Comment: That is true.  `while cave not in Set(["1", "2"]):`

Comment: since python 2.4 there is a `set` [builtin](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset), so `{'1', '2'}` or `set('12')` works too

Answer (score 13):

(1) For variable and function names, `check_cave` (underscore) rather than `checkCave` (camelcase) are standard in python.

(2) The line `def chooseCave` needs to be unindented

(3) Your main game loop could probably be neatened up:

```
while True:
    display_intro()
    check_cave(choose_cave())
    print("Would you like to play again? (yes or no)")
    if input() not in ('yes', 'y'):
        break
```

(4) conventionally you should put the main game loop in a function called `main()` [and add](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do)

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

at the end.

(5) More a matter of taste, but I'd find it more elegant to write choose_cave like this:

```
def choose_cave():
    while True:
        print("Which cave will you choose? (1 or 2)")
        cave = input()
        if cave in ('1', '2'):
            return cave
```

Answer (score 6):

## `print` and multiline text

Your `displayIntro` uses several `print` calls to output multiline text. You may consider rewriting them like this:

```
def displayIntro():
    print("""
You are in a land full of dragons. In front of
you are two caves. In one cave the dragon is
friendly and will give you his treasure. In the
other, the dragon is greedy and hungry and will
eat you on sight"""[1:])
```

This way you can easily apply 80 columns rule for your program output.

`"""` operator starts (and ends) multiline string. `[1:]` trims leading newline.